# How to re-run the test with different data using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Currently we are re-running the test when a Test Fails using [TestNG iRetryAnalyzer](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/IRetryAnalyzer.html).

**Problem that we are facing is:**

We have a Test to 'Add a user'. For the first time after adding a user, in the process of checking the success message exception occurred (Timeout/NosuchElement) etc But the user is added in the database.

Now again when we re-run the test with same data, the Test Fails as user is already Added.

How can i overcome this??

As here the Data, the user email id unique field. Atleast I should be able to change the Email Id when im re-running it for the second time.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to create a unique, fake email address that you don't need to actually use, you can always append a date/time stamp to some base email you get from your DataProvider:

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
 public void emailTest(String userName, String emailShortname) {

 //Get the current time
 long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

 //append it to the email from your DataProvider
 StringBuilder emailBuilder= new StringBuilder();
 emailBuilder.append(emailShortname).append("_").append(time).append("@gmail.com");

  //do user creation code below using emailBuilder result...
```

I would say that if you are going to do these sorts of tests using Selenium, you're going to fill up your database with junk test IDs, so I'd suggest your team create a mechanism to clean these out either as part of the test run or after it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if there is a way to delete a user. You should use that in the @aftertest method and remove that user.

This way the next time you will be again able to use the same email id irrespective of the test is successful or not.

If not and if the email id is never verified ( I mean like some confirmation email which you use to confirm the user)  you can create fake email id on the fly like xyz123@gmail.com. If the email id is verified then i guess you are in trouble.